# Java - JComboBox cannot be shown

Tags: java, swing

I just want to create a JComboBox. And, I paste the following code in https://www.compilejava.net/ and nothing is shown in the window. So, what's wrong with the code? Or does the online compiler have problems? If so, are there any online compiler that works?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 

public class test{

private JFrame f; //window
private JPanel p; //layout


private JComboBox<String> j; //pull down menu

public static void main(String[] args){
   new test();
}

public test(){
   f = new JFrame("title of window");
   f.setVisible(true); 
   f.setSize(600,400);
   f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   p = new JPanel();
   p.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

   String[] bookTitles = new String[] {"Effective Java", "Head First Java",
                                "Thinking in Java", "Java for Dummies"};
   JComboBox<String> bookList = new JComboBox<>(bookTitles);
   p.add(bookList);

   f.add(p);
}

}
```

Comment: Don't call `setVisible(true)` until **after** adding all components to your GUI. Else you're displaying it when it's unfinished.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels How come I can display JLabel when I call setVisible(true) before adding JLabel?

Comment: What JLabel, as I seen no JLabel in the code above? Regardless, even if it works in one situation and not in another, it is recommended in general that you call `setVisible(true)` after adding components. It makes common sense, no?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you so much. I will call it at the last line